# can global filters have Singleton or Transient Scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC, just a question on life cycle on global filters.
I created a global filter(Result Filter) as:

```
public class MessageAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
   private int GetNum { get; set; } = 0;
   ...
   public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
   {
       GetNum += 1;
       WriteMessage(context, $"<div>The Num is:{GetNum }</div>");
   }
   ...
   private void WriteMessage(FilterContext context, string msg)
   {
      byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"<div>{msg}</div>");
      context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   }
}
```

so then I ran the application, and the Num output increments each time I refresh the page from 1, 2, 3....etc

then I registered the `MessageAttribute` in `startup.cs` as:

```
services.AddTransient<MessageAttribute>();
services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options =>{
   options.Filters.Add(new MessageAttribute());
});
```

so I expected the Num output to be "1" all the time  no matter how many times I refresh the page, becuase `MessageAttribute` has been registered as 'transient", which means a new instance of `MessageAttribute` is created every time for each new request, but when I ran the application, the Num output still incremented from 1 to 2, 3 ... every time I refresh the page, doesn't mean that global filters can only registered as :

```
services.AddSingleton<MessageAttribute>();
```

and somehow asp.net core MVC just overwrited my registration with the statement above, is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the behaviour:
When you pass a value to the add method you are somehow creating a singletone instance of the filter. MVC will use the exact instance that you have been created:

```
var alwaysUseThis = new MessageAttribute();
options.Filters.Add(alwaysUseThis);
```

If you pass a type to the Add() method then MVC will create the filter every time it needs to. **Note that it's the MVC filter pipeline that creates the filter object not the Service Provider:**

```
options.Filters.Add<MessageAttribute>();
```

If you want your filter to be resolved like other dependencies the you should use the **AddService()** method:

```
options.Filters.AddService<MessageAttribute>();
// services:
services.AddTransient<MessageAttribute>();
```

With this kind of registration you can use any lifetime you need with your filter (transient, singleton,..).